# Android Emulator LDPlayer HTTP proxy tunnel not working - help

Tags: applications

i am running remote host: Windows 10  connected to an openvpn and running an android emulator on LDPlayer

i wont to run a proxy on android emulator for HTTP and all app traffic should go through the HTTP proxy...

i have tryed several different android softwares and either its not working ore i get my openvpn IP from remotehost

the only thing which works is the HTTP proxy via chrome with below settings

adb shell settings put global http_proxy :

kindly help me out what i am missing ore doing wrong ? i wont to tunnel all traffic UDP/TCP and SSL through the HTTP proxy  also the apps

kindly help me out i am struggeling with this thing for few days now

softwares i have tryed :

shadowsocks
webtunnel
proxifier
Dpitunnel
androidproxy server

and many more

Comment: kindly someone ? i will give 50 usdt to whoever helps me solve this issue i need this solved asap thanks

Comment: You need an emulator that supports direct network access aka. "Bridged Mode" (in this mode the VM directly communicated to your router, it even gets it's own IP in your LAN). All the other modes use some sort of proxy on the host OS to process network requests (this is the reason you always end up in your OpenVPN).  All VirtualBox based VMs should support bridged mode networking. Android in VirtualBox works, e.g. using GenyMotion or you could try to install AndroidX86 inside VirtualBox. But IMHO a pure Linux instead of Android inside VirtualBox would be much easier...

Comment: i tryed to install vmware android 1st.  it works very very slowly pain in the ass...  2.second  i have the same problems  i only didnt try to use bridged mode  ...  so you are saying  theres no way on using proxy for apps and browser in android emulator ? no way arround this ?

Comment: A VPN is working on IP layer (OSI level 3) and proxies work on TCP level (OSI level 4). If a VPN is active a proxy have to use it because the OS performs the IP routing. The proxy has no influence on such things as it is on a different layer.